# How to make one line thicker than the others using axis objects

Tags: python

I have a dataframe that I am plotting. I need to change the lower limit on the y axis to 0 and more importantly make the line for Argentina thicker than the other lines.

I have read the csv file into Python and plotted it, now I just need to make adjustments to the plot.

debt = pd.read_csv('http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~dbackus/Data/debt.csv')

debt = debt.set_index(['Year'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

debt.plot(ax = ax, linewidth = 2)

Answer (score 1):

something like that?..

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
debt = pd.read_csv('http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~dbackus/Data/debt.csv')

debt = debt.set_index(['Year'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
debt['ARG'].plot(ax = ax, linewidth = 1)
debt['DEU'].plot(ax = ax, linewidth = 3)
debt['GRC'].plot(ax = ax, linewidth = 5)
```